# Writing file using StreamWriter takes forever & auto-reloads the window

Tags: c#, io, streamwriter

In my program, I'm using the `Window_Loaded` event to write my App.config file to the .exe's directory, as I'll be needing it for the connectionString in there.

It works perfectly fine, however it seems to be really slow when using StreamWriter and it appears to reload the window as soon as it's written.

With this I mean: The Window loads completely (controls are rendered etc.), MessageBox at the end of my code shows, but the file is still not there.
After that, the window vanishes, re-appears, shows the messagebox again & only THEN is the .config file there, fully written and encrypted.

Also, even before the file is written, for some reason the rest of the code in my Loaded event seems to keep working, instead of the Loaded event pausing until the StreamWriter is finished.

I'm out of ideas, are there any ways to improve the speed at which the file is written and how I can properly halt the program's execution until the writing is complete?

My current code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string loc = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

    if (File.Exists(loc + ".config"))
        File.Delete(loc + ".config");

    string result = "";
    using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Hub.Resources.Hub.exe.config"))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    //I've also tried using File.WriteAllText(...), same result
    using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(loc + ".config"))
    {
        wr.Write(result);
    }

    //Encrypt config file
     Configuration conf = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    ConfigurationSection s = conf.GetSection("connectionStrings");
    if (s != null)
    {
        s.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");
        s.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
        conf.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
    }
    //Show messagebox to notify me (purely informational, will be deleted after it's finished)
    //This messagebox seems to be shown twice, once before the file is written, once after it's written & encrypted.
    MessageBox.Show("Finished Loading");
}
```

PS: During debugging, this all happens completely fine, no window being reloaded and the file appears instantly, as it should.

Comment: How do you know StreamWrites reloads the window? "Appears to"?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's my antivirus which is forcing the .exe to run in Sandbox mode first.

Wasn't a code error, once I added my .exe to my AV's exclusions, it works 100% correctly as if it was debugging.

Appearantly Tencent thinks my program is a Trojan though, no clue as to why, but I must say it's kind of funny :-)

[VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/ffa722e977f8c1078acae0684e4c28cb5add29c6037d7c93f91d64c05b39e8fa/analysis/1432562022/)

So if anyone else has the problem of a window loading twice or not working as it should. Try adding your .exe to your AV's exclusions list ;-)

Comment: Is ten cents the actual value of the antivirus? :)